# What is our stance on website recommendation questions?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

What is our stance on website recommendation questions?  Are they on-topic or off-topic? Assume that the website recommendation pertains to data science.

Example:

> Is there any web demo that returns the k nearest words given a word using GloVes (English)? http://bionlp-www.utu.fi/wv_demo is great but only has word2vec.
>
> [image]

Answer (score 3):

I generally prefer them to be rephrased as the underlying problem that's being solved, not as a question about web sites that have an answer to the problem. If you can construe the question that way (or edit it lightly) I'd leave it open.

These are generally closed as 'primarily opinion-based' if they're really just asking what the best site is.

If such a question has upvotes and useful answers, I'll usually convert it to a wiki. If people are getting value from it I'd rather go ahead and make an exception.

Comment: Agree with Sean here. Blatant 'I wanna do this, pl suggest a website' style posts are bad (obviously). Except for that, well-worded questions with info on what the underlying problem is, would be welcome :)